# select between with value range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
select * from purchase_items where item_code between '180' and '186'
```

I have a table purchase_items, for example, I have the following value(s).

```
item_code
180
182
183
1852563
186cf2564
186cf2564
187sa5635
```

If I select between `180` to `187` the all values display.

But I need the range between `180` to `183` it should display the following:

```
180
182
183
```

And if I give the range `186cf2564` to `187sa5635` it should display:

```
186cf2564
186cf2564
187sa5635
```

Only how do I get it to display the correct output?

Comment: SHOW YOUR SQL QUERY WHAT ARE YOU TRYING

Comment: do u always have leading 3 numbers in` itemcode`

Comment: @ShivShankarNamdev please turn off caps in your comments, indicates a Shout

Comment: no it mixed of alpha numerical it may be ICNF1 to ICNF7  we need to take the last number

Comment: You have to search for strings with `in` operator, or u can use `right` or `left` function

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326065/select-range-of-items-in-a-varchar-column-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data, You can select numeric part of the string. It more of hardcode work, if your data is consistent this query works

```
select * from purchase_items where left( item_code,3) between '180' and '186'
```

For Selecting rows  `ICNF1 to ICNF7`

```
  select * from purchase_items where Right( item_code,1) between 1 and 7
```

For 186cf2564 to 187sa5635

```
select * from purchase_items where left( item_code,3) between '186' and '187'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
select * from purchase_items where item_code between '180' and '183'

select * from purchase_items where LEFT(item_code,3) between '186' and '187'
```